# Can we request features for the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

I want to request the following features:

1. The ability to turn off notifications when not using WIFI.
2. The ability to turn off **instant notifications**, and add something like "**receive notifications every 3 hours**" just like on the website, SE sends an email every 3 hours or so, and it doesn't send a notification at all if you already read it on the site. When on a PC, I don't need to receive notifications on my phone as well, so it would be nice if the app could wait for a period of time, check whether or not I have read my notifications, and then send a notification.
3. The ability to customize my feed. I'm a member on too many SE sites, and seeing all of them on my feed is so bad. I want to be able to choose which sites appear on my feed.

Comment: Is this about the Android app (as suggested by the tags) or the Android SE site (as suggested by the title)?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen it's about the app not the site, I edited the title

Comment: Great suggestions! The third one is already planned. The first one probably would not lead to what you expect (less data usage) because the notifications come in through Google's official library which already handles that and only delivers when the phone itself is pinging with Google.

Comment: +1 for #3. Might I also add a way to set the default landing site, instead of an all encompassing Feed. I'm a member on several sites, but only really frequent SO

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi thank you sir, now, I turned off notifications, because I keep receiving so many of them instantly and it's annoying, now that i know that you could implement the second feature, I will go rate it 5 stars on play store :)

Comment: I would also add the ability to flag comments, I only see the option to upvote it or go to the user's profile. Questions and answers can be flagged, so I don't see why comments can't. (I'll also say that I love the app so far, any plans for adding chat?)